# JQuery equally spaced navigation links inside unordered list problem

Tags: jquery, navigation, width, hyperlink

I'm writing a JQuery script which evenly spaces variable-sized horizontal navigation links inside a containing `<ul>`, using margin-right. The algorithm is:

A: Get width of `<ul>` container.

B: Add up widths of all `<li>` items inside container.

C: Calculate right margin for each item except the last `<li>` by subtracting B from A and dividing by the number of `<li>` items in the container, minus 1.

But there is a flaw either in my algorithm or in my code, because the links are overflowing the container. Here is my code. Can you help please?

Thanks,
-Northk

```
    var containerWidth = $('#main-nav ul').width();
    var linksWidth = 0;
    $('#main-nav ul').children().each(function() {
        linksWidth += $(this).width();
    });
    var linkSpacing = Math.floor((containerWidth - linksWidth) / ($('#main-nav ul').children().length - 1));
    $('#main-nav ul').children().css('margin-right', linkSpacing + "px");
    $('#main-nav ul').children().filter(":last").css('margin-right', 0);
```

And the HTML looks like:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#">link-number-2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you give us an idea of what the css looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just assumed some css rules but i believe this is what you were looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/TEDhb/

```
$('#main-nav ul li:not(:last-child)').css('margin-right', linkSpacing + "px");
```

Comment: Thanks Armin, very clever use of :not.

Comment: All, it turned out to be a CSS problem rather than a problem with my script. I was using display:inline-block for my list items and when I changed this to display:block and float:left it worked. Hmmm.

Comment: Yes. As @boyetboy mentioned too, it looks like the JS was working fine, just some css tweaking. The line above was just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Hate to say this, but it works fine for me. [Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMBucknall/GF5zP/) for it (I assumed the minimal CSS). The top part of the code is your code (which works), the bottom commented-out part is my version (which adds nothing but is more efficient).

Comment: Thanks Boyetboy. With your help and Armin's above, I figured out it was a CSS problem rather than an issue with my script.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide by number of LIs, not by number of LIs-1.

Comment: Er, no. The number of gaps between LIs is one less than the number of LIs

Comment: You're right, my bad. The problem is that LI widths are different and simply dividing doesn't work as one LI (especially last one) can be substantially wider.