# Google web fonts in chrome, safari and ie on windows 7 - jagged, thing, and differently sized

Tags: css, fonts, embedded-fonts, webfonts

https://i.stack.imgur.com/usRIP.jpg

That's a little screencap of the headers on a site I am working on. I wanted to use a google web font (quicksand) and it looks great in firefox. However it looks skinny, jagged and worst of all isn't the same size even so it doesn't span the entire menu.

I've tried googling this and it seems this is currently not fixable from what I can tell. Is there any way to use one of these fonts without this problem? The only thing I can think of is using images instead of text but I don't really want to do that.

I think this problem only becomes really apparent with smaller font sizes. But I still think there is a difference in bigger sizes too just not as noticeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a `text-shadow` of the same color as the background:

```
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
```

Comment: Sorry, no idea why I copied that code over. Try the above code (fiddle with the color, as I don't remember if I used `white` or `black` in my test).

Comment: Ok thank you. Using black or a darker grey looks a lot better. It does kind of look like it has a shadow though.. Not exactly the same as the firefox one. Also there is still the issue that it is not taking up the entire width of the menu bar like in firefox. But I supposed that is possibly some other css? http://i.imgur.com/BtJ5r.jpg

Comment: You can use CSS3 box-model for that. Also, try tweaking `letter-spacing`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. This is a major pain to make it look good on all major browsers..

Comment: is there a property for webkit only browsers? as it is I have to see the shadow a bit in firefox.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but you can [negate it for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952861/targeting-only-firefox-with-css).

Comment: If you want nice evenly-spaced menu items, check out my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509183/evenly-spaced-navigation-links-that-take-up-entire-width-of-ul-in-css3/6515301#6515301). It's CSS3, though.